# Convert Received TCP packets to UDP and forward those packet

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp, udp

I have a service that listens on a TCP port and communicates with a peripheral. I'd like to forward the received packets by the service through UDP to an another computer. I don't need handshake with the second computer, just need the data received by the first one. Is there a way to get that using iptables? I could get this by modifying my service to extract the data and send those as UDP, but I'm asking for a more low level way to do that.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get that using iptables?

No. iptables is primarily used to filter data (i.e. pass, reject...), can maybe add small modifications to the packets but cannot be used to transform packets between transport protocols. If you need a small application which can do this try [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat).